# SQL Server IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server

I have to insert data into table but only if it does not already exist.

I check for existing rows using:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM Table1 where id = @id)
```

Will the use of `'X'` improve performance instead of using a column name?

Answer (score 8):

No. You can use `*`,column name, `NULL` or even `1/0`.

As per the ANSI standard, it should not be evaluated. [Page 191 ANSI SQL 1992 Standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

`*` is mentioned in [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259.aspx?ppud=4)

However, a better way is to use MERGE (SQL Server 2008) or simply catch the error. Previous SO answers from me: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there/3408196#3408196), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695863/sql-server-2008-insert-if-not-exits-maintain-unique-column/3695909#3695909)

Comment: @anishmarokey: see my links to my other answers. A unique key in itself does not help, but it does allow try/catch. And it implies an index too which will help performance

Answer (score 0):

It's probably negligible difference.  I think the most common "pattern" I've seen is to just select 1 when you're just checking for existence, but I wouldn't worry about it too much.

```
select 1 from Table1...
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique would be to add a unique constraint on the column. Always insert a record and handle the failure case where that id already existed in the table.