# If/Else statement return select query in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a store procedure for SQL Server.
And it need to be something like:

```sql
Select * from tblSomething
Where param in (If param1 like 'string' select * from tblTable where condition1
            Else select * from tblTable where condition2)
```

The problem all the if else examples print something and don't return select query.
Can you help???

Comment: Is it just me or does this question get more confusing due to the example posted?  Provide sample data, expected results, etc.

Comment: It's just you. This is not a plain SQL SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF param1 LIKE 'string'
    SELECT *
        FROM tblSomething
        WHERE param IN (SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE condition1)
ELSE
    SELECT *
        FROM tblSomething
        WHERE param IN (SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE condition2)
```

Comment: this works but you could also make this a boolean type expression using an OR.  Ya it might be slower but its also smaller in size.  +1 either way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblSomething WHERE param1 like 'string')
  SELECT * FROM tblSomething WHERE param IN (SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE condition1)
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM tblSomething WHERE param IN (SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE condition2)
```

I'm new to TSQL so any comments to improve will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI about IF EXISTS (SELECT *...) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994040/sql-server-if-exists/3994059#3994059 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137433/where-does-the-practice-exists-select-1-from-come-from/6137474#6137474

Comment: Well I see; Thanks for the hint. I'll update it to `EXISTS (SELECT * ...`. And what about `TOP 1` in the query. Will `EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM` be faster than `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM` ?

Comment: Exactly the same. The TOP and select list are ignored (as per ANSI links)

Comment: I'm using this very often and I thought the `TOP 1 0` is faster but now I see it's even slower because it take some additional time to parse the `TOP 1` statement. Thanks man.